# Crash Rescue mission won't trigger with any of the 3 characters

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am about 50% of the way through the game.  I've already done some of the setup missions for The Bureau Raid, and the next mission is "architect's plans".

I realized that I need Taliana for the heist, but no matter how I try, I can't spawn the crash rescue mission.  I've tried with all 3 characters. Other random events spawn (e.g. "Girl Hitchhiking" or Trever vs biker gangs).

Is there anything special I need to do to trigger the "Crash Rescue" event, or does it just have a really low spawn rate?  I know I'm checking [the right spot on the map](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Crash_Rescue), and I've even slept multiple times to advance the game time about a week, and nothing.

Do I need to just go to before I start doing the setup missions for The Bureau Raid?  I really don't want to lose my progress.

Comment: Why not make a different save? Not sure what platform you're on, but certainly on PC you can make additional saves (as well as backing them up). That said, I don't recall doing anything special. If I were you, I'd just continue on.

Comment: @Tas I'll try another save

Comment: Just checking: have you don't the Jewel Store Job yet? It seems the Crash Rescue event doesn't spawn until the jewel store job is complete.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I've done the Jewel store Job, and have all 3 characters unlocked.  I'm 50% of the way into the story, and have done 2 heists after the jewel store too.

Comment: There's a potential fix in this gamefaqs thread. They suggest that approaching from the east never activates her. Check out what they recommend. https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/634490-grand-theft-auto-v/68541719

Comment: @Paul Could you post your comment as an answer so I can give you the bounty?  I was only approaching from the east, and after 2 tries approaching from the west (once with Trevor, once with Michael) the event triggered!

Comment: Posted. Glad you got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a potential fix in [this gamefaqs thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/634490-grand-theft-auto-v/68541719). They suggest that approaching from the east never activates her. Check out what they recommend.

> I haven't messed around with the Epsilon program yet, so I can't help ya there, but for Taliana, I always find her around mid-day, early evening time. I've also noticed (at least for me), that approaching from the east never activates her, I always have to come around the western way. So, instead of going up the east highway, go to the other side of the map and try going all the way around Mt. Chilliad. She should be in the grass in the middle of the road, just before you come up on a tunnel.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried maybe 20 times from the east, and she never spawned.  I tried twice from the west, and she spawned the second time!  Thank you!